# Why is the default implementation of DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken) synchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I was reading the [documentation for `DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and found the following snippet:

> The default implementation invokes the synchronous [Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx) call and returns a completed task. The default implementation will return a cancelled task if passed an already cancelled cancellationToken. Exceptions thrown by Open will be communicated via the returned Task Exception property.

Now, if I were on a spotty/slow network connection and used a database provider that hasn’t overridden `DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken)` (i.e., I’m using something other than `System.Data.SqlClient`), *and* if I plopped that into a UI Button’s event handler, like: (hypothetical code, untested)

```
async void button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var connection = MyProviderFactory.CreateConnection())
    {
        button1.Text = "Opening…";
        connection.ConnectionString = _SomeString;
        try
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync(default);
            button1.Text = "Opened successfully!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            button1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the documentation I quoted, if the connection took long enough to complete, my Form would be “ (Not Responding)” while the connection was being established if the provider hasn’t overridden the default implementation. To prevent this from happening regardless of the underlying database provider, I might as well do `await Task.Run(async () => await connection.OpenAsync());`. Why is the default implementation this way and how is one supposed to know when `Task.Run()` is needed without writing provider-aware code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `await Task.Run(async () => await connection.OpenAsync())` wouldn't execute `connection.OpenAsync()` in the same thread, but it's perfectly reasonable for `connection.OpenAsync()` and `connection.Open()` to depend on thread-local state. They may and generally should pay attention to [`Transaction.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current(v=vs.110).aspx), for instance. If .NET Framework silently executed `connection.Open()` in a background thread, some people would get very wrong results.

Comment: That sort of implicit transaction management API looks dangerous to use and like something to avoid altogether to me…

Comment: Ah, I see, you’re saying that because some providers use thread local storage while opening up a connection the default implementation provided by `DbConnection` *cannot* safely use the threadpool to enable it to return immediately.

Comment: @binki Like it says in the documentation for `Transaction.Current`, you don't generally use it directly. You use `TransactionScope` to manage it, and then it becomes a very useful mechanism. The connection class itself would use `Transaction.Current` directly though, and wouldn't see the intended value if called on a background thread. I didn't say anything about the connection class itself using thread-local storage (I was thinking only about other classes), but you are right, that's another valid possibility.

Comment: I still think that relying on thread local storage makes it fragile in surprising ways. But I say that because I’ve never even heard of that pattern/API before. Now, if there was something like nodejs’s continuation-local-storage to track transaction scopes, that might feel a little safer to me though it’s still not straightforward. Interesting that the scopes thing exists and, yes, I can see how it could unclutter code quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the default implementation this way

In a word: backwards compatibility. In an ideal world, `ConnectAsync` would be an abstract method; however, this was not possible because there were already many `DbConnection` implementations by the time `async` came on the scene.

So, the designers of `DbConnection` had to choose either synchronous or fake-asynchronous (thread pool) implementations. Neither choice provides a great end-user experience.

For an interesting counterexample, consider `Stream`. This is another common base class that faced the same issue, but made the opposite choice (that is, the base `Stream.ReadAsync` implementation calls `Stream.Read` from the thread pool).

> and how is one supposed to know when Task.Run() is needed without writing provider-aware code?

Unfortunately, that is not possible. You have to think of a `Task`-returning member on a base type or interface as meaning *possibly* asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The key phrase in the docs is

> Providers should override with an appropriate implementation.

DbConnection is the base class for implementation specific classes. It has no idea of the underlying implementation, of how to to make it asynchronous. The base class developers opted to provide a simple implementation for providers that did not implement their own Async version.

I agree, the implementation isn't a great one, but about all you can do without knowing the underlying implementation.

What if the Open implementation doesn't use a network? Maybe it just opens a file. There's no generalization that can be made by the base class.

I would expect most providers to implement a real async version of this method, but if you really need to be async from *anyone*, then I'd just wrap it in a run. However if you ran across a provider that didn't support a true async open, it may very well not support a thread safe open either.

Comment: Opening a file would still be a blocking operation for which asynchronous APIs exist and which “faking” asynchronous access with the threadpool ’s help would work even if people recommend against it.

Comment: Yes, opening a file has asynchronous APIs, but the DbConnection class would have no idea that's what's going on. A provider that used file access would have a trivial time implementing a proper OpenAsync, for the base class it would be impossible. Faking it with a threadpool would work, unless Open did something like put the file handle in thread local storage, then it wouldn't work at all. Personally I would just assume that a provider properly implemented OpenAsync if Open could be a time consuming operation.